# Laravel unknown routing error

Tags: laravel-5

I'm making a authentication system with laravel, but there is something wrong. When I'm making a page that only can be viewed by an admin I receive the error:

```
> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:
in RouteCollection.php line 143
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 746
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 54
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

I have now idea what can be wrong.

This is my code:

Routes.php:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'), function () {
  Route::get('users', 'UsersController@index');
});
```

This is my controller (in Controllers/Admin):

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('backend.users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

And this is my view(in views/backend/users):

```
@extends('master')
@section('title', 'All users')
@section('content')

    <div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2> All users </h2>
            </div>
            @if (session('status'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{ session('status') }}
                </div>
            @endif
            @if ($users->isEmpty())
                <p> There is no user.</p>
            @else
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Joined at</th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!! $user->id !!}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#">{!! $user->name !!} </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>{!! $user->email !!}</td>
                            <td>{!! $user->created_at !!}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: What's the url when you see this error?

Comment: http://localhost/public/admin/users or if I try http://localhost/public/users it also does not work!

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` in terminal and you'll get your routes with correct URLs.

Comment: did it worked at all with the Laravel 5.1 default authentication?

Comment: @Hkan when I run php artisan route:list it's saying:
  [ReflectionException]
  Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UsersController does not exist   but that's strange because it does excist! Also the namespaces are correct.

Comment: Does your folder structure also follow the namespace?

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump`?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes, my namespace in UserController.php is: namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

Comment: @Hkan I've tried composer dump but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is your file name and class name exactly the same (case sensitive)?